# How to limit horizontal scrolling using translate3d and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I'm creating a simple slider for angularJS and I just want to limit the scrolling of the items when you click the next and prev. I don't know how to proceed and I need some help here.

What i've done so far.

### [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/liqomeya/1/edit?html,js,output)

Javascript/AngularJS/CSS3 codes only. No plugin, library or jQuery please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made an edit here: http://jsbin.com/liqomeya/4/edit

- updated `slideAmount` to default as `0` (the other setting caused an unnecessary click to start progressing the slides)
- added `slideCurrent` variable - defaulted as `0` (this keeps track of which slide you're on)
- added `if (slideCurrent == 0) { return }` to the `$scope.prev` function (this prevents you from going past the first slide)
- added `if (slideCurrent == $scope.projects.length - 1) { return }` to the `$scope.next` function (this prevents you from going past the last slide)
- added `slideCurrent--` to `$scope.prev` and `slideCurrent++` to `$scope.next` (in order to increment/decrement the slide)
- changed `slideAmount` updates to `160` instead of `200` (each slide is 160px so this makes it line up properly)